# Executing query through HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

**views/registration.php**

```
<form action="classes/registration.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**classes/registration.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 // Define form variables
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password= $_POST['password'];

 // Insert form data into database
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
 VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
 {
    echo "Registration successfull.";
 }
}
```

The problem is, when I click submit, I get a blank page. The query isn't being executed.

I thought the problem might be because my values aren't setup correctly, so I did the following:

```
VALUES ('$_POST['password']', '$_POST['password']')";
```

but that gives me an error, presumably because I am using ' inside of '

So now I am back to square one, unsure of why my query isn't being executed

Comment: add an `else` to print something else. `else { echo 'did not work'; }` or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a blank page because you don't echo something if $_POST submit isn't set.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

is never true as your $_POST['submit'] is never set. You need to give your submit a name, this (the name) is what get's POSTed / what you can access within `$_POST[' /*name of input*/ ']`

Change your form to the following, then you should see your

```
echo "Registration successfull.";
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="classes/registration.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"> <!-- <<<<<<<<<<< here -->
```

As a sidenote, you should absolutely consider using a prepared statement. Running a registration form with your insert query is like an invitation for people keen on ruining your server. You might want to try the query like this:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
$query->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$query->execute;
```

This way, you will be secured against mysql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your file naming and paths seem to be mismatching(as per the file names you provided).

No matter if you keep:

```
views/registration.php
views/classes/registration.php
```

But if you follow:

```
--/classes
         /registration.php

--/views
        /registration.php
```

[*Note: '`--/`' is the path of your root directory*]

Then the form action `classes/registration.php` won't go anywhere.
So change it:

```
<form action="../classes/registration.php" method="post">
```

I suggest to follow the naming convention:

**filename**- for pages with HTML forms, and

**filename_action**- for action pages

Also notice the possible error cases mentioned by user baao in the other answer.